# JS generated radio selection- how to make the first position a default one

Tags: javascript, radio-button

i'm trying to customize my shop based on prestashop with a new feature, and i'm stuck. I have a JS generated radio selection of payment methods, but i can't figure out how to make the first one (i = 0) checked by default.
Payment methods are numbered and the first one is i=0.
i tried `if (i == 0) {'checked="checked"' }` but i doesn't work.

Here's the code that generates the payment methods:

```
$('.payment_module').each(function(i)
        {
        var a = $(this).find('a');
        html += '<table class="resume table table-bordered'+(currentPaymentMethod == a.attr('href') ? ' selected' : '' )+'"><tr>';
        html += '<td class="td1_payment"><input type="radio" name="id_method_paymend"  id="payment_method_id_'+i+'" '+(currentPaymentMethod == a.attr('href') ?  : '' )+' value="'+i+'" class="wysylka_w_payment" data-href='+a.attr('href') if (i == 0) {'checked="checked"' }+' /></td>';
        var img = $(this).find('a').css('background-image').replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '');
        html += '<td class="td2_payment"><label for="payment_method_id_'+i+'" class="img_w_payment"><img src="'+img+'" alt="" /></label></td>';
        //$(this).find('img').remove();
        html += '<td class="td3_payment"><label for="payment_method_id_'+i+'" class="opis_w_payment">'+a.html()+'</label></td>';
        html += '</tr></table>';
        $(this).attr('id', 'payment_method_'+i+'');
    });
```

Any ideas? I'm guessing the solution might be simple, but i don't know JS that well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `if` within the middle of an expression. You can use the conditional operator, though (just like the earlier one with `currentPaymentMethod`):

```
html += '<td class="td1_payment"><input type="radio" name="id_method_paymend"  id="payment_method_id_'+i+'" '+(currentPaymentMethod == a.attr('href') ?  : '' )+' value="'+i+'" class="wysylka_w_payment" data-href='+a.attr('href') + (i == 0 ? ' checked="checked"' : '') +' /></td>';
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Let's break that into multiple lines to make it clearer:

```
html += '<td class="td1_payment"><input type="radio"';
html += 'name="id_method_paymend"  id="payment_method_id_'+i+'"';
html += (currentPaymentMethod == a.attr('href') ?  : '' ); // <== The earlier one
html += 'value="'+i+'" class="wysylka_w_payment" ';
html += ' data-href='+a.attr('href');
html += (i == 0 ? ' checked="checked"' : '');              // <== The added one
html += ' /></td>';
```

Other notes:

- The conditional using `currentPaymentMethod` is a syntax error, it needs something between the `?` and the `:`
- You probably want quotes around the `data-href` attribute's value
- Note the space before `checked=`, so it's not rammed up against the `data-href` value
- Suggest adding a space before `name=` and `value=` for the same reason

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now i understand more of what i'm reading. I did it the way you suggested, but it still doesn't work. I'll keep trying, maybe i'll figure it out. It seems that there is a span on the final site that changed classes to "checked" when i choose a payment method but i can't seem to figure out where does it come from.